# Placement of Chapter Number in Makechapterstyle

Tags: spacing, chapters

In this code, I'm not able to move the chapter number, only the title. The chapter number should be at the same height as the chapter title. What command can I use? The chapter title should not be moved.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

 \usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}


 \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}   % select the language
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}           % input encoding
 \usepackage{mathptmx}                 % font size extension
 \usepackage{blindtext}                % blindtext
 \usepackage{xcolor}                   % extended colors
 \usepackage{calc}                     % \setlength minus ...


 % --- fancy chapter style ---
 \makechapterstyle{combined}{
   \setlength{\midchapskip}{-4cm}
   \setlength{\afterchapskip}{3cm}
   \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
   \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{80}{80}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\flushright\chapnumfont\textcolor{gray}{\thechapter}}
   \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
     \raggedright\chaptitlefont\parbox[t]{\textwidth -2cm}{\raggedright##1}}
 }
 \chapterstyle{combined}
 % --- end of chapter style definition ---


 \begin{document}
 \chapter{First Chapter}
 \blindtext[4]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: At the same height, but on what horizontal location? Flushed to the right? Protruding into the left margin? Right before the chapter title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}   % select the language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}           % input encoding
\usepackage{mathptmx}                 % font size extension
\usepackage{blindtext}                % blindtext
\usepackage{xcolor}                   % extended colors
\usepackage{calc}                     % \setlength minus ...
\usepackage{graphicx}

 % --- fancy chapter style ---
\makechapterstyle{combined}{
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{-\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{3cm}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{1cm}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{80}{80}\selectfont\color{gray}}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\selectfont\color{gray}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \hfill\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \parbox[b]{2cm}{\raggedleft\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
     }%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \parbox[b]{\textwidth-2cm}{\raggedright\chaptitlefont##1}
    }%
  }
}
\chapterstyle{combined}
 % --- end of chapter style definition ---

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the only information provided in the question was that the number should appear at the same height as the chapter title, but no information was given regarding the horizontal placement, I chose to place the chapter number flushed left; you can change this according to your needs.